# How to add custom js file to pixture_reloaded Drupal 7 theme?

Tags: drupal-7

Trying to add file by `drupal_add_js(…)` in `pixture_reloaded_process_html` function takes no effect

Answer (score 0):

Simply you should add files in `pixture_reloaded.info` theme file.

```
stylesheets[all][] = relative_path/mystyle.css
scripts[] = relative_path/myscript.js
```